# Execution time limit exceeded with PHP random number generator

Tags: php, random, sleep

I'm trying to make a program that prints a random number every 3 seconds, but my mistake is "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded", sorry but I have almost no experience in PHP and I know the functions to clear the memory, I appreciate your help .

```
ejemplo();
function ejemplo() {
    $c=null; 
    $c=mt_rand(60,200); 
    sleep(3); 
    clear();
    ejemplo(); 
}
```

Comment: My code  php 
ejemplo();
function ejemplo()

{
    $c=null;
    $c=mt_rand(60,200);
 
 sleep(3);
    clear();
 ejemplo();
}

Comment: This is not a memory problem. Your script is running for longer than the maximum execution time set by the server. You could work around it, but there are other ways to do this depending on what you're actually trying to do with these numbers

Comment: [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/set_time_limit), which only makes sense for console programs however, not in web pages. Also: having that function recurse to itself doesn't make sense. This needs a while loop if it's meant to run forever.

Comment: sounds like something that should be done client side - with js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use explicit flushing to load a random number every three seconds:

```
<?php

ob_implicit_flush(true);

ejemplo();
function ejemplo() {
    $c = mt_rand(60,200);

    ob_end_flush();
        echo $c . "<br>\n";
    ob_start();

    sleep(3);
    ejemplo(); 
}
```

However, you can't clear the output once it's outputted (without using JavaScript).

Another method would be to just use JavaScript:

```js
var refresh = function() {
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = Math.round(Math.random() * 140) + 60;
};

refresh();

setInterval(refresh, 3000);
```

```html
<div id="number"></div>
```

Comment: even with flush, various caching can get in the way, this is much better done client side.

Comment: Not to mention that some servers might ignore PHP's request to flush, or a server using gzip.

Comment: Works great thanks, but no way to be running a weather function for PHP ?, what happens is I'm doing a program that brings information from a database, but this query it should be executed each time and always n I get "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" because it is monitoring a system, my program works well but can not find the form that is running without exceeding the memory page must be basically always open.

Comment: Another method would be to show one bit of information and then call it with ajax every three seconds. Would you want some sample code demostrating this?

Comment: can help with a more specific example I have a php file in which a query is made the result is stored in several variables but I recovered in variables javascript that already I have but should estarse refresando variables therefore must be running the query each but not so often as, in short what I have is Actuamente something;
file 1:
<? php
....

$ c = query 1;
$ b = query 2;

Comment: <? php
....

$ c = query 1;
$ b = query 2;

?>

file 2:

<htlm>
<head>
<? php include (file1.php)?>
</ head>
<scritp>
var c = '<? php echo $ c>';
var b = '<? php echo $ b>'

</ script>
</ htlm>

It works but my variables remain fixed my database value changes constantly, please help.

Thanks and regards.